# In regards to dm-crypt with LUKS, what is meant by "passphrase strengthening"?

Tags: fedora, security, encryption, luks, dm-crypt

On the Fedora [wiki](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Disk_Encryption_User_Guide#Choosing_a_Good_Passphrase) it is mentioned that LUKS offers this protection.

> LUKS does provide passphrase strengthening but it is still a good idea to choose a good (meaning "difficult to guess") passphrase.

What is it exactly and how is it accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar phrase appears in other places (e.g., [this Red Hat 5 page](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/installation_guide/ch29s02)), where a bit more detail is given:

> - LUKS provides passphrase strengthening.
>
>   - This protects against dictionary attacks.

Just from that I would expect it to mean that the password is being salted and probably has other improvements applied to the process (e.g., hashing it N times to increase the cost).

Googling around, this phrase seems to have first appeared in conjunction with LUKS around 2006 in [the Wikipedia article on Comparison of disk encryption software](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Comparison_of_disk_encryption_software). There the description of "passphrase strengthening" goes to [the article on "Key stretching"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_stretching), which is about various techniques to make passwords more resilient to brute-force attacks, including using [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2). And indeed, LUKS1 did use PBKDF2 (LUKS2 switched to Argon2), [according to the LUKS FAQ](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/wikis/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#10-luks2-questions).

So that's what passphrase strengthening means in this context: using PBKDF2 and similar to make passwords more difficult to crack. The FAQ also has a short description:

> If the password has lower entropy, you want to make this process cost some
> effort, so that each try takes time and resources and slows the attacker
> down.  LUKS1 uses PBKDF2 for that, adding an iteration count and a salt.
> The iteration count is per default set to that it takes 1 second per try on
> the CPU of the device where the respective passphrase was set.  The salt is
> there to prevent precomputation.

For specifics, LUKS used SHA1 as the hashing mechanism in PBKDF2 (since 1.7.0 it's SHA256), with iteration count set so that it takes about 1 second. See also [section 5.1 of the FAQ: How long is a secure passphrase?](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/wikis/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#5-security-aspects) for a comparison of how using PBKDF2 in LUKS1 made for a considerable improvement over dm-crypt:

> For plain dm-crypt (no hash iteration) this is it.  This gives (with
> SHA1, plain dm-crypt default is ripemd160 which seems to be slightly
> slower than SHA1):
>
> ```
> Passphrase entropy  Cost to break
> 60 bit              EUR/USD     6k
> 65 bit              EUR/USD   200K
> 70 bit              EUR/USD     6M
> 75 bit              EUR/USD   200M
> 80 bit              EUR/USD     6B
> 85 bit              EUR/USD   200B
> ...                      ...
> ```
>
> For LUKS1, you have to take into account hash iteration in PBKDF2. For a current CPU, there are about
> 100k iterations (as can be queried with `cryptsetup luksDump`. The
> table above then becomes:
>
> ```
> Passphrase entropy  Cost to break
> 50 bit              EUR/USD   600k
> 55 bit              EUR/USD    20M
> 60 bit              EUR/USD   600M
> 65 bit              EUR/USD    20B
> 70 bit              EUR/USD   600B
> 75 bit              EUR/USD    20T
> ...                      ...
> ```